# Pentaho: Change the Row seperator to character other that CR+LF

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want to change the default row seperator from CR+LF to some other character because we have CR+LF characters coming in our data as well. We want to change it to \u001. How can I do that? is there any option to specify it while writing to a file? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a "Text file output" component which does indeed not offer to freely select the row seperator.

However, it allows you to select `No new-line terminator`. By chosing this option and adding another constant field to your output stream just containing the seperator string `\u001` you should be able to achieve the desired effect.

This solution will give you an extra column seperator. If this disturbs you, you may want to actually add the seperator string to the last output fields of your flow (after converting this field to string representation if required).